# How can I provide a Private Policy for my app without creating a dedicated Website for it?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge, privacy-policy

On trying to submit my app to the Microsoft Store, it tells me that I need to provide a Privacy Policy, because users supposedly can make their location, etc., known when using the app:

[image]

I guess the reason why they say that is because the user is directed to Internet pages when clicking on a button and some images in my app?

In any case, how can I provide an URL without creating a website for just that purpose? Would it work to create a public page on jsfiddle and use that URL?

Comment: The private policy URL is required if your product accesses, collects, or transmits Personal Information. This is mentioned in the [Store Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/store-policies#105-personal-information). Store doesn't have requirements about what kind of privacy policy URL, it is recommended to use a dedicated Website for it. There is no guarantee that the public page will pass the review.

Comment: My app doesn't do those things. It does take the user to amazon product pages if they click certain images or a button, though. I don't know if that is what the hangup is...

Comment: If the store detects that your packages declare capabilities that could allow personal information to be accessed, transmitted, or collected, the store will mark this question as Yes, and you will be required to enter a privacy policy URL. This behavior is mentioned here:[Privacy policy URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/enter-app-properties#privacy-policy-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To host the policy for free, without having a website, you can signup on:

- GitHub Pages
- Medium.com
- Google Sites

Some privacy policy generators provide page hosting for the policy text.

Answer (score 2):

The reason app stores enforce these things these days is that ultimately they'll suffer in the public eye if they're not good stewards of their users' data, regulators these days are looking more closely (under Kamala Harris, Google/Apple and Apple started to intensify their efforts) and at last: many things can be considered personal information.

You can definitely use a jsfiddle or a similar setup such as a page hosted on Github. There are a gazillion options here, though many are probably not that pretty.

I'd suggest you look into privacy policy generators too, they may help you to get the text done as well. You can google them, you'll find some here in SO as well, but mostly these questions are closed because it's not strictly connected to programming (I def. have suggestions to make).